# Is it possible to change tinyMCE custom Toolbar ListBox values after tinymce init

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Following example is add a custom dropdown to tinyMCE, is it possible to change again after init tinyMCE? for example, after init the tinyMCE, update the list again by another button by different list.
    https://codepen.io/tinymce/pen/JYwJVr

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 500,
  toolbar: 'mybutton',
  menubar: false,
    content_css: [
    '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'],

  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.addButton('mybutton', {
      type: 'listbox',
      text: 'My listbox',
      icon: false,
      onselect: function (e) {
        editor.insertContent(this.value());
      },
      values: [
        { text: 'Menu item 1', value: '&nbsp;<strong>Some bold text!</strong>' },
        { text: 'Menu item 2', value: '&nbsp;<em>Some italic text!</em>' },
        { text: 'Menu item 3', value: '&nbsp;Some plain text ...' }
      ],
      onPostRender: function () {
        // Select the second item by default
        this.value('&nbsp;<em>Some italic text!</em>');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any choice that I can update only for the custom dropdown. This is not what good way but the only way I can make it work. So what I did was remove tinymce and re-add it again.

```
tinymce.remove();
tinymce.init({
 selector: 'textarea',
     setup: function (editor) {
               var self = this;
                editor.addButton('mybutton', {
                  type: 'listbox',
                  text: 'myList',
                  icon: false,

                  onselect: function (e) {    

                    editor.insertContent(this.value());
                  },
                  values: newList,
                  onPostRender: function () {
                    // Select the second item by default
                    this.value('&nbsp;<em>Some italic text!</em>');
                  }
                });
            }
});
```